# Href in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I just want to ask how can I have different links in my GridView.

Here is my HTML code for my GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridsummary" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                HorizontalAlign="Left">
               <Columns>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="sstat" HeaderText="STATUS">
                   <ItemStyle Width="250px" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                   </asp:BoundField>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="ctr" HeaderText="COUNT" >
                   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="150px" />
                   </asp:BoundField>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="sstat" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="<a href='webViewDelivered.aspx'>View</a>" />
               </Columns>
               <HeaderStyle CssClass="GRIDVIEW_TITLE" />
               <RowStyle CssClass="GRIDVIEW_DETAILS" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my c# code when loading the page.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dsSummary = dm.MainDash(Session["Username"].ToString(), "");
            gridsummary.DataSource = dsSummary.Tables[0];
            gridsummary.DataBind();


            string sDelivered = string.Empty;
            string sNoAirway = string.Empty;
            string sIntransit = string.Empty;
            string sReturned = string.Empty;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dsSummary.Tables[0];
            List<string> slistPostal = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                if (dr[0].ToString() == "DELIVERED")
                {
                    sDelivered = dr["HTML"].ToString();
                    Delivered.InnerHtml = sDelivered;
                }

                if (dr[0].ToString() == "FOR PROCESSING")
                {
                    sNoAirway = dr["HTML"].ToString();
                    NoAirway.InnerHtml = sNoAirway;
                }


                if (dr[0].ToString() == "IN TRANSIT")
                {
                    sIntransit = dr["HTML"].ToString();
                    Intransit.InnerHtml = sIntransit;
                }

                if (dr[0].ToString() == "RETURNED")
                {
                    sReturned = dr["HTML"].ToString();
                    Returned.InnerHtml = sReturned;
                }

            }
        }
```

What I want is something like this:

If I select the first row of my GridView the third BoundField will be this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="sstat" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="<a href='webViewDelivered.aspx'>View</a>" />
```

If I select the 2nd row the third BoundField will change to this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="sstat" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="<a href='webViewForProcessing.aspx'>View</a>" />
```

When a different row is selected href will be modified depending on the page that I want to load, is there a condition for that?

PS: My stored procedure is quite long so for your reference sstat is equal to the conditions in above.. for example in my SP i have `select 'DELIVERED' AS sstat`

Comment: Your code says GridView. But your question title and text says `datagridview`. And you tagged it `datagridview` despite the fact that the description for that tag says it's about a control in the Windows Forms libraries. Make sure you're using the right name for things.

Answer (score 0):

Use TemplateField not BoundField

```
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <HyperLink ID="RedirectBtn" runat="server"
                OnClick="RedirectBtn_Click" />

        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

You can add whatever you want in OnRowDataBound event of the grid after that. If your RowDataBound event is called Grid_RowDataBound

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.DataItem == null)
        return;

    DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

    HyperLinkbtn = e.Row.FindControl("RedirectBtn") as HyperLink;
    b.NavigateUrl = "write your link";
    //if you want to open new tab
    b.Target="_blank";

}
```

You are adding the event to the grid like this:

> OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound"

**If you want you can make it with a tag, if your href is static and you don't need to make changes for every row.**

```
<asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="YourHeaderText">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a target='_blank' href='Your link'>Text/a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Nothing shows in my gridview when I added your template field, and did you declare HyperLinkbtn?

Comment: @eljon_i3 in both case something is visible I don't know what you do wrong.